# htaccess redirect incoming links to certain pages to homepage

Tags: php, linux, .htaccess

Google has indexed certain pages in my website that I wouldn't like users to access directly but from the homepage (forexample).

Using .htaccess how can I redirect incoming outside links to certain pages and make it go to my homepage?

Comment: Why don't just add the rel="nofollow" to the links? or make them private to authenticated (or logged in) people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent Google from indexing specific pages on your site in future, use a [noindex meta tag](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=93710).

To send specific pages to the home page, e.g. `http://mysite.com/somddir/somepage.htm` add the following to your .htaccess in the root directory of your site

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

# add a rule like this for each page you want to redirect
RewriteRule ^somedir/somepage\.htm$  / [L,NC,R=302]
```

Be sure to use `R=302` and not `301`, which is permanent.

Answer (score 1):

i think you must use HTTP_REFERRER in RewriteCond :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} http\:\/\/example.com/
RewriteRule (.*)$ index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^testpage.htm$  / [L,NC,R=302] `